# Ассоциации Rails - Автоматический выбор текущего пользователя как автора поста

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеются две модели:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
end
```

и

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Миграция:

```
class AddUserIdToHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :hotels, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Форма создания нового поста про отель:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@hotel, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input  :title %>
  <%= f.input  :star_rating, collection: 1..5 %>
  <%= f.input  :room_description, as: :text %>
  <%= f.input  :price_for_room %>
  <p>Address</p>
  <%= f.select :hotels_country, priority: ["Ukraine", "Russia", "Europe"] %>
  <%= f.input  :state %>
  <%= f.input  :city %>
  <%= f.input  :street %>
  <%= f.input  :breakfast_included %>
  <%= f.input  :photo, as: :file %>
  <%= f.association :user %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Вопрос: как реализовать, чтобы при создании поста про новый отель  в таблице hotels в поле user_id был текущий пользователь? При выше приведенной реализации получается, что в строке <%= f.association :user %> есть выпадающий список всех пользователей из таблицы users, а необходим только текущий, чтобы каждый пост автоматически был привязан к пользователю, который его создал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например в контроллере перед сохранением отеля:
@hotel.user_id = current_user.id
можно и через hidden_field в форме, только этот вариант не секурен

Answer (score 2):

Можно проще?

```
@hotel = current_user.hotel.create(params)
```

Comment: Да! И это ещё и куда безопаснее.